# Saving webpage in single file

Tags: firefox

I want to save any webpage as a single file (stand alone) using Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8051/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I was unaware, but have developed something similar based upon wget... But that was some time ago: I wonder if wget has been improved to do something like this?!